# Check if column name occurs in a specific data frame in a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I hava a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2), NA, NA, NA)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01")
```

And a list of data frames like this:

```
id_list <- list(data.frame(id = c(1, 1), date = c("2017-03-01", "2017-01-01")),
                data.frame(id = c(2, 2), date = c("2017-02-01", "2017-03-01")))
```

My goal is to fill the date columns of `df` with 0s and 1s depending on whether or not in `id_list` a date occurs in the data frame of an id. Hence, the final output should be:

```
> df_final
  id 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01
1  1          1          0          1
2  2          0          1          1
```

In reality, `df` has 170 columns and 2400 rows; `id_list` has 2400 data frames each with 1 - 100 rows and 20 columns. I should stress that the data frames in `id_list` are not sorted by date.

**EDIT:** I just tried LAP's solution for:

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2), 0, 0, 0, 0)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-04-01")
id_list <- list(data.frame(id = c(1, 1),
                           date = c("2017-03-01", "2017-01-01"),
                           stringsAsFactors = F),
                data.frame(id = c(2, 2, 2),
                           date = c("2017-02-01", "2017-03-01", "2017-04-1"),
                           stringsAsFactors = F))
```

Unfortunately, the output was

```
> df
  id 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01 2017-04-01
1  1          1          0          1          0
2  2          0          1          1          0
```

instead of

```
> df
  id 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01 2017-04-01
1  1          1          0          1          0
2  2          0          1          1          1
```

**EDIT2:** I had a bad typo `2017-04-1` instead of `2017-04-01`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop over the columns while simultaneously using the column name as input for an `sapply` call to loop through `id_list` and check for the occurence of said name within the dataframes:

```
for(i in names(df)[-1]){
  df[, i] <- as.numeric(sapply(id_list, function(x) i %in% x[, "date"]))
}

> df
  id 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01
1  1          1          0          1
2  2          0          1          1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to `rbind` the 'id_list' and then use a `row/column` indexing method to assign the 1 values.  If the other values should be 0, then it is better to construct with a 0 instead of NA

```
d1 <- do.call(rbind, id_list)
i1 <- cbind(match(d1$id, df$id), match(d1$date, names(df)[-1], nomatch = 0))
df[-1][i1] <- 1
df
#   id 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01
#1  1          1          0          1
#2  2          0          1          1
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(c(1, 2), 0, 0, 0)
colnames(df) <- c("id", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-03-01")
```

Comment: If i run `df[-1][i1] <- 1` I get:  "Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, i1, value = 1) : 'value' is the wrong length"

Comment: @Joe I am using only your example data and it is working fine for me.  The `df` is created with 0 instead of NA though

Comment: Akrun, you're right, it works for my original `df` and `id_list`. The error occurs for the new pair (see my above edit).